# Xcodebuild & Jenkins: How to rename the product after build

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, jenkins, xcodebuild

I would like to rename the .ipa file created after the build process to apply some company internal nomenclature. We use Jenkins and the Xcodebuild plugin. There seems to be no way to rename the product via the Xcodebuild plugin, so I wondered what the appropriate shell script would be.

Consider that I have a $filename at hand.

Comment: Use a simple mv command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an execute shell build step to run after the xcodeplugin runs.  Something like this:

```
mv $WORKSPACE/build/Distribution-iphoneos/<your ipa filename>.ipa $WORKSPACE/build/Distribution-iphoneos/<new filename>.ipa
```

You'll have to check the WORKSPACE directory on your build server or slave to get the exact location of your .ipa file.

Comment: Right now I am doing this, still it doesn't satisfy me... Isn't there any environment variable to return the name of the product Xcodebuild created?

Comment: None that I could find when I was converting our builds to the xcodebuild plugin, unfortunately.  I think I tried for a while to find a way to do it like you wanted but I eventually gave up and was forced to use what I originally posted.